# How do I pass more than one parameter to the selector in 'scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:'

Tags: objective-c, parameters, userinfo

I know user info is used to pass a parameter, but how do I pass more than one of these?

I'm guessing I have to use an object, but as I am fairly new to objective-c I don't really know if this is right and how to go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a wrapper object, an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` with the multiple objects you need to pass and pass that wrapper object in `userInfo`. On the receiver retrieve the objects from the wrapper object.

Example code using a NSDictionary for the wrapper:

Calling code:

```
NSString *obj1 = @"string1"; 
NSString *obj2 = @"string2"; 
NSDictionary *wrapper = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:obj1, @"Object1", obj2, @"Object2", nil];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:) userInfo:wrapper repeats:NO];
```

Receiving timer code:

```
- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
    NSDictionary *wrapper = (NSDictionary *)[theTimer userInfo];
    NSString * obj1 = [wrapper objectForKey:@"Object1"];
    NSString * obj2 = [wrapper objectForKey:@"Object2"];
    // ...
}
```